# MySQL Get time difference from first and nth record

Tags: mysql

I have a series of records inserted into a log. Each series is identified by a id. So

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE action_id = x ORDER by created;
```

But I want to get the first record inserted, and the last. These records have a created timestamp. So I want to find the difference between the first and last record, in seconds.

**Update:**

I've tried

```
SELECT max(created) - min(created) FROM log WHERE action_id = 21 ORDER BY created;
```

it returned 0.000000

The time difference for these two are clearly a few minutes.

```
max(created)    min(created)
"2013-02-11 14:30:34"   "2013-02-11 14:27:31"
```

its stored as DATETIME. Engine is InnoDB.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: `SELECT max(timestamp) - min(timestamp)`?

Comment: you can get last record by max(timestamp) and first by min(timestamp) and the difference by SELECT max(timestamp) - min(timestamp)

Comment: I have tried that. It returned 0.00000

Comment: Please post the values for SELECT max(timestamp), min(timestamp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that `created` is being stored as a string.

Try this:

```
select max(cast(created as datetime)) - min(cast(created as datetime))
```

If you try something like:

```
select '2012-01-01 10:44' - '2012-01-01 10:41'
```

You'll get a value of 0.  MySQL converts the strings to numbers, stopping at 2012, and then takes the difference.

Comment: its stored as DATETIME. Engine is InnoDB.

Comment: oohhh ok, its a DATETIME field, but its not a timestamp. Will try now.

Comment: Also, are you sure the `where` clause is choosing more than one row?

Comment: this did it. SELECT max(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created)) - min(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created)) FROM log WHERE action_id = 21 ORDER BY created;